# Trouble understanding the definition of Independence of System of Sets

Tags: probability, independence

In Probability theory, independence of system of sets $(\mathcal A_i)_{i\in I}$ (e.g. for sigma algebras) is defined as for every finite $J\subset I$ **and every choice** of $A_i\in\mathcal A_i$ for every $i\in J$ it holds that $$P\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i\right) = \prod_{i\in J} P(A_i).\qquad(\star)$$

I don't understand how this definition is meant. Especially the part I highlighted. Let's say I have $I={1,2,3}$ and $\mathcal A_1 = \{A,B,C\}$, $\mathcal A_2 = \{\{\Omega, \emptyset\}$ and $\mathcal A_3 = \{A,B\}$. Do I understand it correctly that I have to check whether $(\star)$ holds, i.e. for

- $J =\{1\}$: $P(A)=P(A)$; $P(B)=P(B)$; $P(C)=P(C)$.
- $J =\{2\}$: $P(\Omega)=P(\Omega)$; $P(\emptyset)=P(\emptyset)$.
- $J = \{3\}$: $P(A)=P(A)$; $P(B)=P(B)$.
- $J = \{1,2\}$: $P(A\cap\Omega) = P(A)P(\Omega)$; $P(A\cap\emptyset)=P(A)P(\emptyset)$; $P(B\cap \Omega)=P(B)P(\Omega)$; $P(B\cap\emptyset)=P(B)P(\emptyset)$; $P(C\cap\Omega)=P(C)P(\Omega)$; $P(C\cap\emptyset)=P(C)P(\emptyset)$.
- $J=\{1,3\}$: $P(A\cap A) = P(A)P(A)$; $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$; $P(B\cap A) = P(B)P(A)$; $P(B\cap B) = P(B)P(B)$; $P(C\cap A)=P(C)P(A)$; $P(C\cap B)=P(C)P(B)$.
- $J=\{2,3\}$: $P(\Omega\cap A)=P(\Omega)P(A)$; $P(\Omega\cap B)=P(\Omega)P(B)$; $P(\emptyset\cap A) = P(\emptyset)P(A)$; $P(\emptyset\cap B)=P(\emptyset)P(B)$.
- $J=\{1,2,3\}$: $P(A\cap \Omega\cap A) =P(A)P(\Omega)P(A)$; $P(A\cap\Omega\cap B)=P(A)P(\Omega)P(B)$; $P(A\cap\emptyset\cap A) =P(A)P(\emptyset)P(A)$; $P(A\cap\emptyset B)=P(A)P(\emptyset)P(B)$; $P(B\cap \Omega\cap A) =P(B)P(\Omega)P(A)$; $P(B\cap\Omega\cap B)=P(B)P(\Omega)P(B)$; $P(B\cap\emptyset\cap A) =P(B)P(\emptyset)P(A)$; $P(B\cap\emptyset B)=P(B)P(\emptyset)P(B)$; $P(C\cap \Omega\cap A) =P(C)P(\Omega)P(A)$; $P(C\cap\Omega\cap B)=P(C)P(\Omega)P(B)$; $P(C\cap\emptyset\cap A) =P(C)P(\emptyset)P(A)$; $P(C\cap\emptyset B)=P(C)P(\emptyset)P(B)$.

(I am sure there are some typos but just to get the general idea of the definition).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Every choice.  So for $J=\{1,2,3\}$, there are 12 assertions.

Comment: Thanks! 

Edit: I got your comment wrong in the first place. Sorry